# How do i take spaces in a string input in c++

Tags: c++

I created a code that executes a specific operation based on the input of the user, some operations are named with spaces between in it, but when i input the operation names, its not executing the operation where as when i remove the space the operation is getting executed can someone help me with this.

Here is a code snippet:

```
string user_command;
    cout << "Enter the operation: ";
    cin >> user_command;

    if (user_command == "Value Check"){
        valueCheck();
```

Comment: When reading strings, the `>>` operators reads *space delimited* "words". Perhaps use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: well richard and some programmer dude where do i place the std::getline can you please tell me

Comment: @SriGovind You place it at the point where you want to read the user input. I'm guessing at the line with `cin`.

Comment: well can you answer it along with the code please actually kinda new to c++

Comment: I would encourage you to glance over the link provided to learn how to use `std::getline()` yourself. What you learn will stick better.

Comment: thank you very much sweenish, i will definately do it

Comment: @SriGovind Why? If you are new to C++, you surely want to learn. Reading docs is a necessary skill to learn.

Comment: Guys i found the way to fix it
its fixed now
thank you everyone :D

Comment: yeah Quimby you are right